# JWebBrowser DJ Native Swing freeze GUI

Tags: java, swing, swt, djnativeswing, jwebbrowser

This is the example i got from http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/Snippets.html with a little bit modification.

```
package View;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import chrriis.common.UIUtils;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;

/**
 * @author Christopher Deckers
 */
public class GoogleMaps extends JPanel {

  public GoogleMaps() {
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Native Web Browser component"));
    final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Create an additional bar allowing to show/hide the menu bar of the web browser.
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 4, 4));
    JCheckBox menuBarCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Menu Bar", webBrowser.isMenuBarVisible());
    menuBarCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(menuBarCheckBox);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }
}
```

and then in another JFrame, I am trying to open this browser by clicking a button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        GoogleMaps maps = new GoogleMaps();
        UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();
        NativeInterface.open();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DJ Native Swing Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(maps, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        NativeInterface.runEventPump();
    }
```

But then it freeze my GUI. What should I do in this case?

Any pointers will help

Comment: Why the `SWT` tag?

Comment: @Baz: maybe `chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.*`?

Comment: @trashgod The `nativeswing` part and the fact that pretty much everything is swing rather than SWT mislead me.

Answer (score 0):

NativeInterface.runEventPump() function is a blocking one. It should be run in another thread.

In your case it could be solved like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!NativeInterface.isEventPumpRunning())
                NativeInterface.runEventPump();
        }
    }).start();
```